# MasterPage ASP.Net and Jquery on click issue of css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, master-pages

I know in Jquery and masterpage is have litle different in syntax. The solution is is like this :

```
$("<#%=divName.ClientID%>").click()
```

But it only for the div/another element **ID** certainly with *runat=server*. The problem is how about if used **class of css**, I mean I have of some class of the "DIV", how to click it with jquery in Masterpage. It's not working. I have been try in the single page without masterpage and it working.

So how to click a div class with jquery over masterpage?

```
  $('.empty').click(function () {
        alert('hallo it was clicked from class');
    });
```

Comment: Have you got your path jquery to correctly set in your masterpage? Is the jquery library being loaded? A class selector should not care if it is hosted in a master page or not. Check that jquery is loaded and inspect the HTML of your element to ensure that the class is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you use master pages should be irrelevant to using jQuery with class selectors. I have used classes and master pages numerous times with no issues.

```
<div class="empty">
    This div is clickable
</div>

<script>
$('.empty').click(function () {
   alert('hallo it was clicked from class');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about `divName.ClientID`. just add a div to the marster page. this should be a client element. remove `runat=server` if you have. then just call your click event using the class or id.

```
<div class='empty'>test</div>

<script>
$('.empty').click(function () {
   alert('hallo it was clicked from class');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!

The issue is the div has absolute position. So it wont to be clicked. Actually the div is generated from the code.
The solution is place the div that have absolute position into a parent DIV.

Thanks Friends.